# Node.js + Socket IO + Apache + PHP cheap webservers?

Tags: php, node.js, webserver, socket.io

I am new to using node.js and socket io and I am currently hosting my php website on a server, now that I am going to be adding node js and socket io to my website I will need hosting that will allow me to have those, are there any out there or will I need to have my own? I am hoping to have a cheap hosting service as this is just to have my site hosted while in development, once I am finished with it I plan to have my own server set up.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to start with node.js and socket io if you lack knowledge about linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [DMEHosting](http://www.dmehosting.com/) as a VPS to use for development. Their cheapest Linux VPS is more than affordable and serves your purposes. It will also get you into the basics of setting up a web server on Linux via SSH, which is essential. I recommend reading up on an article on setting on a VPS on Cent OS. Just Google that. You don't really need to learn how to use Linux for now. Just know how to navigate directories and follow tutorials on setting up your own web server.

Edit: Keeping this post as is for historical purposes, but I now recommend an EC2 instance or DigitalOcean.

Comment: I purchased DMEHosting over VPS as You recommended, now I have some problems, please tell me can I connect by putty? how I can install php, in web console when I run php install command, it shows me an error that package does not exist.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Since the web console is working, this means you should have root access. Open up putty and connect via port 22. Put in your IP address, username as root, and root password. Depending on which operating system is installed by default, try an apt-get install php5 or yum install php5. I'm sure once you get root access via putty, you can figure this out by googling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) of Node hosting solutions. However, if you want to be able to have Node.js + PHP and Apache, you will need to use your own server, like a VPS. Popular options are [Linode](http://www.linode.com/), [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/), [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) and [Fanatical](http://fanaticalvps.com/). Note that the VPS option will require good knowledge of Linux.

Comment: An EC2 micro instance would work well, too.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have really any knowledge of Linux so that wouldn't be an option for me, and I would need node.js, php, and apache, so I guess my only option really is my own server, as I thought. There is one server I believe, provided by amazon that does this, (i believe, someone was telling me briefly about it) however it's quite expensive, and would be worth the money to buy my own.

Comment: @DylanCross those are all equivalent to having your own server. Even if you went out and bought a real physical machine, you would need Linux knowledge to set it up. All those services do is rent you space on those machines so you don't have to buy one yourself. I would suggest you use one of the things I listed and just practice and get to know Linux.

Comment: @ceejayoz indeed, forgot about EC2. Added link, thanks.

Comment: Oh, they have to run on linux? My assumption of servers were that I could have it run any OS, windows or mac, and it be much like a regular computer, just dedicated to my website though. (I'm not much of a server techny at the moment, either, which is something I will surely have to get better at, so I guess at some point I will need to learn enough linux to set up a server) Thanks.

Comment: @DylanCross oh, sorry, yikes. No, they can run on Windows just fine haha. I just didn't think about that.

Comment: @DylanCross in this case, I think [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) might be your best bet. Node.js was ported to Windows to work with that platform, so you should have no trouble integrating it.